Data transfer with f2py
context
I want to code an optimizer module (by myself) using f2py. Let's suppose the data are relatively "gigantic" so that it makes sense to use fortran. Sorry, I cannot provide an example, since I want to make the library multi-purpose
problem
I may want to use f2py to make calculations on big arrays faster by writing some routines in fortran. I do not know how much speedup to expect because of data transfer between python and fortran.

Can someone provide insight on those data transfer mechanisms? How limiting are those transfer? Provide a solution if necessary?
Compare with some other alternatives (like numba, jax, numpy)?


Welcome to [so]. Please read How To Ask a Good Question. "please help me" is not a question; we don't write code to specification. You are expected to study the problem ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

I am asking if developers met this problem and how they solved it. Maybe the question is not fit for this stack. Possible fit in my opinion are "software engineering" and "computer science" stacks.
